# Difference between 'academic knowledge' and 'professional knowledge'

Tags: word-choice

What's the difference between **academic knowledge** and **professional
knowledge**? Which would be better when expressing a student's knowledge/understanding/mastery of English language? (Here English is taught as a second language.)

I'm going to use this in my CV to describe one of my teaching experience. The complete sentence is **'Devised courses on English phonetics, grammar and textbook review to consolidate the student’s academic knowledge'**

Comment: *Academic* would be what the *books and teachers* teach. Professional is what the society, corporate and business teach!

Comment: Can you give a sentence where you're going to use the adjective? It would be easier to answer your question.

Comment: Thank you for your advice V, I've added some details in my question

Answer (score 1):

Your question revolves around the difference between **theory** and **practice**

**Academic knowledge** is learnt in school, it is usually **theory based** since one spends most their time **learning concepts and theories**

**Professional knowledge** is knowledge which is gained through the **application** of theory into practice while **on-the-job**.

A student's experience would primarily be **academic** based given the choice between academic or professional.